# php string compare

Tags: php, strcmp

I'm trying to compare a specific part of a url to get a list of the endings (which are resource/'location' where location is either state initials or a string). I'm using this to populate a drop down menu. This works well with the 2 letter states, but when I compare the strings it still shows duplicates. This is the code I am working with, and 'National' is the repeated string that does not get filtered out.

```
$url = explode("/", $row['url']);
if(strcmp(trim($location[$url[2]]),trim($url[2])) != 0)
{
    $location = array($url[2] => $url[2]);
    echo '<option>'.$location[$url[2]].'</option>\n';
}
```

Is there a better way to compare strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in_array()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
$location = array();
$url = explode("/", $row['url']);
if(!in_array($url[2], $location))
{
    $location[$url[2]] = $url[2];
    echo '<option>'.$location[$url[2]].'</option>\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you even using strcmp?
Also, why are you resetting $location?

```
$url = explode("/", $row['url']);
if(trim($location[$url[2]]) != trim($url[2]))
{
    echo '<option>'.$url[2].'</option>\n';
}
```

Not sure what would cause the duplicates though, think I'd need to have an example to play with to figure that out.

EDIT: Ignore the above, after reading the other answer I see what you're trying to achieve. The question wasn't very clear on that.

Comment: I'm brand new to web development. I'd much rather like to use a list to add elements, but I didn't find a good substitute. I figured that was the way to add new elements to the array.

Comment: Yeah no worries being new to it all. I think I just didn't understand what you were trying to achieve in the first place - it was my bad!